# how to change img src using javascript in a php page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a php page with some image thumbnails. what i want to do here is to view the thumbnail zoomed in another img on a mouseover event.

Thats the php code:

```
echo"<tr><td><a href='$imgrow[location]' target='_blank' > <img src='$imgrow[location]' height='50' width='50'  id='thumbnail' onmouseover='hover();'></img></a></td></tr>";

echo "<div style='left:60px; top:3px; width:500px; height:400px; position:absolute;border-style:none;'><img src='' height='400' width='500' id='zoomimg' ></div>";
```

Thats the javascript code:

```
function hover() {
var zoom = document.getElementById("zoomimg");
var tnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
zoom.setAttribute('src', tnail.src);
}
```

unfortunately, this code is not working
any ideas?

Comment: Do all your images have unique IDs?

Comment: try `onmousemove="hover"` (without the parenthesis and semicolon).

Comment: "some" thumbnails? Do they all have the same id? If so, there's your problem. id's must be unique across the entire document.

Comment: yes, they do have the same id

Comment: i mean i have to generate the thumbnails in a loop, so thats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function hover() {
    var zoom = document.getElementById("zoomimg");
    var tnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    zoom.setAttribute('src', tnail.src+"?"+(new Date()).getTime()));
 }
```

Although Im not sure of the syntax(most probably is a wrong way to do so), but do you get the idea, Im adding query at the end to change it right away without reloading the webpage what I suppose is you want to do.